# Vagrant Laravel Homestead - error when running vagrant up

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have followed the tutorial on https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead and when running the step 'vagrant up', I get the following error message (below)
Any ideas what the problem is? Running latest version of Oracle VirtualBox and the latest version of Vagrant. Regards

--

```
C:\Users\Anders\Vagrant\Homestead>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead-7
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.16) and guest (5.0.12) do not match.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
dkms is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Copy iso file C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the
 box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
mount: block device /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso is write-protected, mounting rea
d-only
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.0.16 - guest version is 5.0.12
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.0.16 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.0.12 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Stopping VirtualBox Additions ...fail!
(Cannot unload module vboxguest)
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Stopping VirtualBox Guest Addition service  ...done.
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules ...done.
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
You should restart your guest to make sure the new modules are actually used

Installing the Window System drivers
Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.0.16. Some
 functionality may not work as intended.
In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/Anders/Vagrant/Homestead
    default: /home/vagrant/Code => C:/Users/Anders/Code
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3`,
actimeo=1 home_vagrant_Code /home/vagrant/Code
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant`,actimeo=1 home_vagran
t_Code /home/vagrant/Code

The error output from the last command was:

unknown mount option `actimeo=1'
valid options:
  rw         mount read write (default)
  ro         mount read only
  uid       =<arg> default file owner user id
  gid       =<arg> default file owner group id
  ttl       =<arg> time to live for dentry
  iocharset =<arg> i/o charset (default utf8)
  convertcp =<arg> convert share name from given charset to utf8
  dmode     =<arg> mode of all directories
  fmode     =<arg> mode of all regular files
  umask     =<arg> umask of directories and regular files
  dmask     =<arg> umask of directories
  fmask     =<arg> umask of regular files

C:\Users\Anders\Vagrant\Homestead>
```

--

vagrant file:

--

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))
    elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath)))
    end

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end
end
```

--

yaml file:

--

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/Vagrant/Homestead/homestead.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
      type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
      hhvm: true

databases:
    - homestead
```

Comment: Your Homestead.yaml file contains 'tabs' instead of spaces.

Comment: thanks - seems to have fixed something. now i get another error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [issue you're experiencing](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8410) with Homestead has been documented in Github. There is a workaround provided, which is as follows:

> Solution: Remove type: "nfs" on your folders of Homestead.yaml.
>
> http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html
>
> "Windows users: NFS folders do not work on Windows hosts. Vagrant will
> ignore your request for NFS synced folders on Windows.

---

**Original Answer** (for the question before it was edited)

Now  the issue seems to be with your ssh key, or lackthereof.

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/Anders/.ssh/id_rsa (Errno::ENOENT)
```

The section [in the guide you linked](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead) titled Set Your SSH Key has the following instructions to help you generate one (trimmed to the relevant Windows instructions):

> Set Your SSH Key
>
> [...]
>
> On Windows, you may install [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and use the `Git Bash` shell included with Git to issue the command above. Alternatively, you may use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html) and [PuTTYgen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html).
>
> Once you have created a SSH key, specify the key's path in the authorize property of your `Homestead.yaml` file.

If you are not that comfortable with commandlines, I would recommend using the PuTTYgen method.

Comment: thanks Brian Morton -> I issues the commands thru my GitShell on Windows and solved the issue. New problem edited above

Comment: @AHL could you clarify exactly what your current issue is? The original question is quite confusing now with all the edits!

Comment: @AHL I have updated the answer to reflect the updates to your question.

Comment: thanks Brian - this was the issue. Another question: where do I put my code so that I can access it at http://192.168.10.10:8000/ ? I put a file under C:\Users\Anders\Vagrant\Homestead\Code but when I try to access http://192.168.10.10:8000/ in my browser in the host machine I get a "Unable to Connect" error

Comment: @AHL you may need to open a separate question since that is a separate issue, but as a start you can run `sudo netstat -lnutp` and see if `:8000` and `nginx` show up anywhere in that list (they should). If they do not, that means `nginx`, the webserver on the vagrant box` is not running.

Comment: Removing type: "nfs" fixed it for me. Win 10,  Vagrant 1.9.7, laravel 5.4, homestead.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with your Homestead.yaml file in ~/.homestead directory. I need see the file content to help you more.

After you had fixed the indention style to use only space characters, the another problem happenned because you not generate a pair (public and private) of keys yet. To do that:

`mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cd ~/.ssh`

`ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -C "you@domain.com"`

You can let the default file name (id_rsa), type the password and repeat the same password.

Comment: thanks Lucas -> I issues the commands thru my GitShell on Windows and solved the issue. New problem edited above

Comment: I never used the vagrant-login neither vagrant-vbguest and maybe the latter is causing the problem. Try remove it `vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vbguest` and install the nfs kernel server in your host machine `sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server`.

Comment: Can I install the nfs-kernel-server on a Windows machine also? Or is this only applicable if the host is Linux based?

Comment: On Windows you can install a vagrant plugin to add the support for NFS: `vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd`. (https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else ends up here via Google and didn't read all the comments too well (like I did).

I ran into the same issue of not being able to `vagrant up` with the following error:

```
Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o actimeo=1,nolock,uid=1000,gid=1000 var_www_dev.mybox /var/www/dev.mybox

The error output from the command was:

  fmask     =<arg> umask of regular files
```

As Lucas mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111020/vagrant-laravel-homestead-error-when-running-vagrant-up#comment60018278_36111065) Windows users can install the [vagrant-winnfsd](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd) plugin which allows you to use NFS shared folders in Vagrant and Homestead).

So I solved this error by running `vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd` followed by a `vagrant up`.